# Use a graphing utility to graph the function and find the absolute extrema of the function on the given interval.

Tags: integration

Use a graphing utility to graph the function and find the absolute extrema of the function on the given interval. (Round your answers to three decimal places. If an answer does not exist, enter DNE.)
f(x) = −x + cos 3x, [0, /6]
For the max, I got (0,1), which is correct as I plugged in 0 to y to find the left endpoint. Then, to find the right endpoint, I plugged in /6 into y and got -2.152, so my answer was (/6,-2.152), but this was wrong. Any pointers?

Comment: Your answer should have been $-\pi/6+\cos(3(\pi^2)/6)\approx  -0.3030$

Comment: that answer was wrong too!

Comment: I just realized π/6 isn't the minimum, as there's another point, so how would you find that?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find the maximum and minimum values that the function takes on the given interval.  There's no reason why the maximum and minimum have to occur at the endpoints of the interval.

Note that the problem is not to evaluate the function at the maximum and minimum values of $x$.

If you graph this function, you can see that the maximum does indeed occur at the left endpoint of the interval, but the minimum is not at the right endpoint.

There is probably a way to find the minimum using the graphing utility mentioned at the beginning of the problem.  Some graphing calculators have this capability.  Otherwise, you probably want to calculate the derivative of the given function, and then find where the derivative is 0 on the given interval.  More information here: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/absextrema.aspx

Comment: How would you solve it then? All the demo problems solve it like that!

Comment: @mathematicianuserprecalc I edited my answer.

Comment: Ok, so I found that the derivative is -2, but how would you find the minimum from the graph?

Comment: You can find an approximate value for the minimum using the graph simply by looking at the graph, and seeing where the graph is lowest on the given interval.  You can also use a graphing calculator.  If you are in precalculus, as your username suggests, I suspect that using a graphing calculator is what you are supposed to do.  I'm not sure what you did to calculate the derivative, but it's not -2.